# Modal not showing up in react with react-bootstrap

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-modal, react-bootstrap

I am trying to create a modal to have a login/register pop-up when clicking on the `NavBar.Item` Login/Register.

My modal is defined as below:

```
import React from "react";
import '../assets/styles/GenericTheme.css'
import { Modal } from "react-bootstrap";

class LoginRegisterModal extends React.Component {  
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {show: false};
    }

    open = () => {
        this.setState({show: true});
    }

    close = () => {
        this.setState({show: false});
    }

    render() {  
        return (         
     //   <Modal show={this.state.show} onHide={this.close} dialogClassName="popup-inner">
        <Modal show={this.state.show} fade={false} style={{width: "200px", display: "block"}}>
            <Modal.Body>test</Modal.Body>
        </Modal>
        );  
    }  
}  

export default LoginRegisterModal;
```

In the NavBar, I have added the reference to the Modal as below:

```
import React, {}  from 'react';
import { Navbar, Nav, NavDropdown } from 'react-bootstrap';
import SearchForm from '../HeaderFooter/SearchForm';
import SiteLogo from '../../assets/images/village-logo.svg';
import '../../assets/styles/HeaderTheme.css'
import LoginRegisterModal from '../LoginRegisterModal';


class NavHeader extends React.Component {

    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {showLogin: false};
    }

    openLogin = () => {
        this.setState({showLogin: !this.state.showLogin});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
            <Navbar className="village-header" width="100" expand="lg">
                <Navbar.Brand href="/">
                    <img
                        src= { SiteLogo }
                        width="214"
                        height="28"
                        className="d-inline-block align-top"
                        alt="Village"
                    />
                </Navbar.Brand>
                <SearchForm />
                <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
                <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
                    <Nav className="mr-auto village-header">
                    <Nav.Link href="/discover">Discover</Nav.Link>
                    <Nav.Link href="/create">Create</Nav.Link>
                    <Nav.Link href="/howitworks">How it Works</Nav.Link>
                    <Nav.Link ref="LoginRegisterModal" eventKey={1} href="#" onClick={this.openLogin}>Login/Register</Nav.Link>
                    <NavDropdown title="Profile" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
                        <NavDropdown.Item>Firstname LastName</NavDropdown.Item>
                        <NavDropdown.Divider />
                        <NavDropdown.Item href="/profile">Profile</NavDropdown.Item>
                        <NavDropdown.Item href="/messages">Messages</NavDropdown.Item>
                        <NavDropdown.Item href="/settings">Settings</NavDropdown.Item>
                        <NavDropdown.Item href="/logout">Logout</NavDropdown.Item>
                    </NavDropdown>
                    </Nav>
                </Navbar.Collapse>
            </Navbar>
            <LoginRegisterModal show={this.state.showLogin} />
            </div>
            );
        }
}

export default NavHeader;
```

When I click on the Login/Register:

`<Nav.Link ref="LoginRegisterModal" eventKey={1} href="#" onClick={this.openLogin}>Login/Register</Nav.Link>`

nothing happens, no pop-up or modal is shown. Also I have added the line below in the NavBar

`<LoginRegisterModal show={this.state.showLogin} />` but nothin change. I tried also by adding a `className` and forcing the `z-layer` to 2 but it's not working as well.

Any ideas ?
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your modal component isn't "listening" for any passed props, i.e. the `show` prop being passed from `NavHeader`. A quick dirty would be to implement the `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle function to check for the `show` prop value change. Also use the `show` prop value to set initial state in the case it's displayed open upon mounting.

```
class LoginRegisterModal extends React.Component {  
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      show: props.show, // use the initial show value
    };
  }

  open = () => {
    this.setState({ show: true });
  }

  close = () => {
    this.setState({ show: false });
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    const { show } = this.props;
    if (prevProps.show !== show) {
      if (show) {
        open(); // open if parent says to
      } else {
        close(); // close if parent says to
      }
    }
  }

  render() {  
    return (         
    //   <Modal
    //     show={this.state.show}
    //     onHide={this.close}
    //     dialogClassName="popup-inner"
    //   >
      <Modal
        show={this.state.show}
        fade={false}
        style={{width: "200px", display: "block"}}
      >
        <Modal.Body>test</Modal.Body>
      </Modal>
    );  
  }  
}
```

This allows the parent to to toggle the modal's display state, but what if the modal is closed/dismissed from within. You may want some way to signal back out to the `NavHeader` that the modal was closed so it can "sync" its state. The `onHide` prop  does that, and you have it commented out. I suggest also exposing out to the `LoginRegisterModal` API an `onHide` prop.

```
close = () => {
  this.setState({show: false});
  this.props.onHide();
}
```

The the parent uses as such

```
<LoginRegisterModal
  show={this.state.showLogin}
  onHide={() => this.setState({ showLogin: false })}
/>
```

This however, creates code duplication. It may be a better design to make `LoginRegisterModal` a controlled component and simply pass the `show` and `onHide` props passed from `NavHeader` to the internal `Modal` component of `LoginRegisterModal`.

```
const LoginRegisterModal = props => (
  <Modal
    // pass props on through to Modal
    {...props}
    // set any props here that you don't want "overridable" by passed props
    fade={false}
    style={{ width: "200px", display: "block" }}
  >
    <Modal.Body>test</Modal.Body>
  </Modal>
);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you give me an example of controlled component ? I am new to react

Comment: @Seb Sure. I added a simple example to the end of my answer.

Comment: my code is crashing and also, I do not see where the call to componentDidUpdate is done

Comment: This is what I got as error : 'Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.'

Comment: @Seb Can you be more specific about what is crashing? What component is looping state updates?

Comment: So I have added your code and when I click on login to trigger the modal, I have the error message I have copied before your reply. It seems that using `componentDidUpdate` is not making React happy

Comment: @Seb, Oh, shoot, yeah, I see why, if the entire conditional expression evaluates to false then it will constantly set state to close the modal. I updated answer. Now it will only enter the outer if block if props *actually* changed, *then* it tests the show/hide condition. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: thanks a lot. it works.... I have a last question. how can we trigger the close of the pop-up by just clicking outside?

Comment: @Seb https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/modal/#modal-props Looks like the `backdrop` prop should handle that, it's `true` by default. Play with the demos in the docs I linked.